# Overflow for slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, css

SO I have a slideshow which works. My Problem ist that some images are over the html width, thats why there is a scroll effect, which I dont want to have. If I use the css property overflow-x:hidden the images over the display are cut off. Is ther any way for removing the scroll effect without cutting off images? 
Here is a picture of my problem: [image]
and under that I hav my working code.

```js
var index = 1;

function plusIndex(n) {
    index = index + n;
    showImage(index);
}

showImage(1);

function showImage(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
    if (n > x.length) {
        index = 1
    };
    if (n < 1) {
        index = x.length
    };
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    x[index - 1].style.display = "block";
}
autoSlide();

function autoSlide() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    if (index > x.length) {
        index = 1
    }
    x[index - 1].style.display = "block";
    index++;
    setTimeout(autoSlide, 2000);
}
```

```css
* {
    /* valid for everything */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background: #FAFAFA;
}

html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

h3 {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 1.5%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #A4A4A4;
    width: 15%;
}

li {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 1%
}
/* slideshow for the products */

.cssSlider {
    width: 100%;
}

.sliderElements {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    transition: left .8s ease-in-out;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.sliderElements:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    font-size: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
/* Product details text slide */

.sliderElements> li {
    float: left;
    width: 8%;
    margin-left: 6%;
    height: 100px;
    /* figcaption move up & down here */
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
/*important to use the input-buttons; change the value to slide more or less 

*/

#slide2:checked~ .sliderElements {
    left: -30%;
}

#slide3:checked~ .sliderElements {
    left: -60%;
}

#slide4:checked~ .sliderElements {
    left: -80%;
}

#slide6:checked~ .sliderElements {
    left: -30%;
}

#slide7:checked~ .sliderElements {
    left: -60%;
}

#slide8:checked~ .sliderElements {
    left: -80%;
}

#slide10:checked~ .sliderElements {
    left: -30%;
}

#slide11:checked~ .sliderElements {
    left: -60%;
}

#slide12:checked~ .sliderElements {
    left: -80%;
}
/* Captiom of the picture position set */

.sliderElements figcaption {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1;
    top: -1%;
    padding: .2em;
    font-size: .8em;
}
/* Images responsive */

.sliderElements img {
    width: 100%;
    border: 4px solid #7F7F7F;
}
/* inputs pushing out of the view */

.cssSlider input {
    position: absolute;
}
/* centering the controls - works in conjunction with inline-block */

.sliderControls {
    text-align: center;
}
/* Controls next to each other */

.sliderControls li {
    display: inline-block;
}
/* Controls identical and round off the corners  */

.sliderControls label {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #FFCC00;
    color: #FFCC00;
    font-size: 0.0em;
}
/* attribute selector and indirect descendant to control the labels  */

.sliderControls label:hover,
#slide1:checked~ .sliderControls label[for="slide1"],
#slide2:checked~ .sliderControls label[for="slide2"],
#slide3:checked~ .sliderControls label[for="slide3"],
#slide4:checked~ .sliderControls label[for="slide4"] {
    background: #ddd;
    color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<!-- ------------------------ viewing window for the FIRST slideshow ----------------------- -->
<div class="cssSlider">
    <h3 id="#mica">Test</h3>

    <!-- inputs to control the slider -->
    <input class="none" type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1" checked="checked">
    <input class="none" type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2">
    <input class="none" type="radio" name="slider" id="slide3">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide4">

    <!-- single slides are created as lists -->
    <ul class="sliderElements">
        <li>
            <!-- -------------------- add more products within the ul-tag -------- -->
            <figure>
                <!--------------------- figure-tag shows the products and the details ---------->
                <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
                <img src="/blume.jpg" alt="Product1" class="product">
            </figure>
        </li>

        <li>
            <figure>
                <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
                <img src="/blume.jpg" alt="Product2" class="product">
            </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <figure>
                <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
                <img src="/blume.jpg" alt="Product3" class="product">
            </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <figure>
                <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
                <img src="/blume.jpg" alt="Product4" class="product">
            </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <figure>
                <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
                <img src="/blume.jpg" alt="Product2" class="product">
            </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <figure>
                <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
                <img src="/blume.jpg" alt="Product3" class="product">
            </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <figure>
                <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
                <img src="/blume.jpg" alt="Product4" class="product">
            </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <figure>
                <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
                <img src="/blume.jpg" alt="Product4" class="product">
            </figure>
        </li>
        <li>
            <figure>
                <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
                <img src="/blume.jpg" alt="Product4" class="product">
            </figure>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Control  buttons-->
    <ul class="sliderControls">
        <li><label for="slide1">1</label></li>
        <li><label for="slide2">2</label></li>
        <li><label for="slide3">3</label></li>
        <li><label for="slide4">4</label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-------------------------------------- ENDING of the FIRST slideshow -------------------------------------->
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to get rid of scrollbar. To achieve that, you must use overflow: hidden; in your desired element.

Comment: If I use overflow hidden only 6 out of 9 images are shown.... they are cut out thats a problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

overflow-x:hidden is important for my slidshow otherwise none of the overflowed images are displayed. I found a solution. I have put overflow-x:hidden into my body {} and now there is noch scroll effect and my slideshow is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `overflow-x: auto` from your `.sliderElements` class

```js
      var index = 1;

function plusIndex(n){
index = index + n;
showImage(index);
}

showImage(1);

function showImage(n){
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
if(n > x.length) {index = 1};
if(n < 1){ index = x.length};
for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
        x[i].style.display ="none";
    }
x[index-1].style.display = "block";
}
autoSlide();
 function autoSlide(){
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
        x[i].style.display ="none";
    }
if(index > x.length){ index = 1}
x[index-1].style.display = "block";
index++;
setTimeout(autoSlide,2000);
}
```

```css
* {
/* valid for everything */
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
background: #FAFAFA;
}

html,
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}

 h3 {
    text-align: left;
  padding: 1.5%;
   margin-left: 10%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #A4A4A4;
  width: 15%;
 }

  li {
    text-decoration: none;
   list-style: none;
     margin: 1%;
    padding: 1%
  }


 /* slideshow for the products */

 .cssSlider {
   width: 100%;
   
 }

  .sliderElements {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
   left: 0%;
  right: 0;
 width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  transition: left .8s ease-in-out;
  /*  overflow-x: auto; */
 }

 .sliderElements:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
   clear: both;
     visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: auto; 
}


/* Product details text slide */

.sliderElements > li {
 float: left;
 width: 8%;
 margin-left: 6%;
 height: 100px;
 /* figcaption move up & down here */
 position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/*important to use the input-buttons; change the value to slide more or less 

*/

#slide2:checked ~ .sliderElements {
 left: -30%;
}

#slide3:checked ~ .sliderElements {
 left: -60%;
}

#slide4:checked ~ .sliderElements {
left: -80%;
}

#slide6:checked ~ .sliderElements {
 left: -30%;
}

#slide7:checked ~ .sliderElements {
 left: -60%;
}

#slide8:checked ~ .sliderElements {
 left: -80%;
}

#slide10:checked ~ .sliderElements {
 left: -30%;
}

#slide11:checked ~ .sliderElements {
left: -60%;
}

 #slide12:checked ~ .sliderElements {
 left: -80%;
  }


 /* Captiom of the picture position set */

 .sliderElements figcaption {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1;
  top: -1%;
  padding: .2em;
  font-size: .8em;
}


 /* Images responsive */

 .sliderElements img {
  width: 100%;
  border: 4px solid #7F7F7F;
 }


/* inputs pushing out of the view */

.cssSlider input {
position: absolute;
}


/* centering the controls - works in conjunction with inline-block */

.sliderControls {
text-align: center;
}


/* Controls next to each other */

.sliderControls li {
display: inline-block;
}


 /* Controls identical and round off the corners  */

.sliderControls label {
  width: 15px;
   height: 15px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 1%;
 border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
  background: #FFCC00;
 color: #FFCC00;
 font-size: 0.0em;
}


/* attribute selector and indirect descendant to control the labels  */

.sliderControls label:hover,
#slide1:checked ~ .sliderControls label[for="slide1"],
#slide2:checked ~ .sliderControls label[for="slide2"],
#slide3:checked ~ .sliderControls label[for="slide3"],
#slide4:checked ~ .sliderControls label[for="slide4"] {
 background: #ddd;
color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
 <div class="cssSlider">
          <h3 id="#mica">Test</h3>

          <!-- inputs to control the slider -->
          <input class="none" type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1" checked="checked">
          <input class="none" type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2">
          <input class="none" type="radio" name="slider" id="slide3">
          <input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide4">

          <!-- single slides are created as lists -->
          <ul class="sliderElements">
              <li><!---------------------- add more products within the ul-tag ---------->
                  <figure><!--------------------- figure-tag shows the products and the details ---------->
                      <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
                      <img src="/blume.jpg" alt="Product1" class="product" >
                  </figure>
              </li>

              <li>
                  <figure>
                      <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
                      <img src="/blume.jpg" alt="Product2" class="product">
                  </figure>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <figure>
                      <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
                      <img src="/blume.jpg" alt="Product3" class="product">
                  </figure>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <figure>
                      <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
                      <img src="/blume.jpg" alt="Product4" class="product">
                  </figure>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <figure>
                      <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
                      <img src="/blume.jpg" alt="Product2" class="product">
                  </figure>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <figure>
                      <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
                      <img src="/blume.jpg" alt="Product3" class="product">
                  </figure>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <figure>
                      <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
                      <img src="/blume.jpg" alt="Product4" class="product">
                  </figure>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <figure>
                      <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
                      <img src="/blume.jpg" alt="Product4" class="product">
                  </figure>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <figure>
                      <figcaption>Name</figcaption>
                      <img src="/blume.jpg" alt="Product4" class="product">
                  </figure>
              </li>
          </ul>

          <!-- Control  buttons-->
          <ul class="sliderControls">
              <li><label for="slide1">1</label></li>
              <li><label for="slide2">2</label></li>
              <li><label for="slide3">3</label></li>
              <li><label for="slide4">4</label></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: Still there is the scroll effect there.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome and firefox

Comment: Works fine in my Chrome. Can't say for Firefox

Comment: If I use overflow.x:hidden the scroll effect goes away, but then not all images are shown.

Comment: Will try in FireFox approx. in an hour

Comment: you can also try to set `ul.sliderElements: { width: 300% }` and `div.cssSlider: { overflow: hidden }` that should help. But pretty sure `overflow-x: auto` for `.sliderElements>li` was the main problem

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you want to hide the scrollbar? If so, you have to use overflow-x: hidden. You have no choice. After use that you can use touchMove event and transform: translate3d(x, y, z) to control the image window position. But that will be a big challenge.
If you want to make this job easier. You can use [iScroll](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/) library. It use the same theory as I said.

Comment: Yes I want the scrollbar removed. For that I used the proberty overflow but the images are cut out. If I use the libary all images will be shown when the slideshow moves?

Comment: If you use overflow, it will cut out the images for sure. iScroll would not cut the images. It 'simply' hide the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

`.sliderElements {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}`

Should remove the scrolling effect

-
Edited

<strike>overflow-x: hidden;</strike>

removing the overflow-x shall not show the scrollbar and display all images

Comment: yes thats removing the scroll bar... but only 6 out of 9 images are shown. So the overflow-x hidden is cutting them out. I can not use that I think.

Comment: Remove the 'overflow-x: auto' entirely

Comment: Are you trying to get all the images to show on the screen then? or just some for the slideshow effect?

Comment: Yes I want them all to show. If I click on the buttons under the images the slideshow moves to the left and new images are there. But if I use the overflow-x: hidden the images are cut off. Otherwise if I dont use it the scrollbar is back .

Comment: Have you tried to remove the "overflow-x" element entirely? Worked for me.

Comment: Yes I tried that @Andy A. But If I remove that the scrollbar is back.